# Amplify Auth and Android: temporary credentials - accessKey, secretKey invalid in postman

Tags: android, authentication, postman, credentials, aws-amplify

i have set up an android app to use amplify auth.

i have allowed it to accept unauthorized (guest) users and google federated sign in.

it all seems to work as expected. i can log in using google sign in and cognito.

i am experiencing a problem with using the temporary credentials generated for the google sign in and the guest user.

i have set up an api in apigateway (the pet example imported into my apigateway). i can access the endpoint using a user with policy allowing invoke api. i test in postman using the users accessKey and secretKey and it works.

it also works when i use the cognito logged in users' idToken.

(i have added allow invoke api to the auth and unauth roles' policies for the identity pool used)

if i use the accessKey and secretKey generated for the guest using this code:

```
 public void getGuestCredentials(View view) {
    Log.i(TAG, "inside getGuestCredentials()...");
    Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
            result -> {
                AWSCognitoAuthSession cognitoAuthSession = (AWSCognitoAuthSession) result;
                Log.i(TAG, "Is user signed in: "+cognitoAuthSession.isSignedIn());

                switch(cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getType()) {
                    case SUCCESS:
                        Log.i(TAG, "success IdentityId: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getValue());
                        Log.i(TAG, "success access key: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue().getAWSAccessKeyId());
                        Log.i(TAG, "success secret key: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue().getAWSSecretKey());
                        break;
                    case FAILURE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "failure IdentityId not present because: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getError().toString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.i(TAG, "default IdentityId: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getValue());
                        Log.i(TAG, "default access key: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue().getAWSAccessKeyId());
                        Log.i(TAG, "default secret key: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue().getAWSSecretKey());
                        break;

                }
            },
            error -> Log.i("AuthQuickStart", error.toString())
    );
```

I get:

"message": "The security token included in the request is invalid."

in postman.

the same with the keys generated for the google signin using this code:

```
//            sign in as federated user using google token (using escape hatch)
        AWSMobileClient mobileClient = (AWSMobileClient) Amplify.Auth.getPlugin("awsCognitoAuthPlugin").getEscapeHatch();
```

//            mobileClient.federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), account.getIdToken(), new Callback() {
mobileClient.federatedSignIn("accounts.google.com", account.getIdToken(), new Callback() {

```
            @Override
            public void onResult(final UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
                //Handle the result
                Log.i(TAG, "mobileClient login result: " + userStateDetails.getUserState().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "success google federation, going to authenticated user page.... ");
```

//                    ************************************************

```
                AWSCredentials credentials = mobileClient.getCredentials();
                Log.i(TAG, "***** secret key: "+credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
                Log.i(TAG, "***** access key: "+credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
```

....

appreciate any help to solve this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

managed to get sorted.

"When you make a call using temporary security credentials, the call must include a session token, which is returned along with those temporary credentials. AWS uses the session token to validate the temporary security credentials. The temporary credentials expire after a specified interval."

i got the sessionToken using this code:

```
((AWSSessionCredentials) AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentials()).getSessionToken();
```